Parquet removal/storage/reuse
We have a parquet floor (not sure about the english name though), something like this, just less new and less nice.

[source]
Because of the renovations I plan to remove them (in order to break the floor under it, move walls, etc.). We are not sure whether we want to have them back after the renovations, but just for the case we need them again:
How best to remove them, store them in order to be able to use them again? (e.g. sanding - i guess if i want to use them again, i need to sand them before applying a new finish. Is it best to sand them now before removal, or after placing them back again just before applying the finish? What else needs to be considered?)

They are not going to come up nicely.
They are tongue and grooved on all edges, and most likely nailed,or possibly glued to the floor. They will crack in ways that will most likely make them unusable.
By the way, I believe that the pattern is called "herringbone"

If you’re very lucky and they do come up easily, sand after reinstallation.

@AloysiusDefenestrate , It is possible, but it is real tedious. THAT is a lot of pieces. Yes definitely sand, they will never level up the same, unless it is a micro-bevel prefinished.

yes, i received the info, that back in the time the house was built (70's) these kind of parquets used to be glued with a bitumen (is this the right word?) adhesive, therefore it makes no sense to salvage them
